# Cypress: redirected to another page(baseurl) on clicking on submit button(form)

Tags: javascript, cypress

when script clicks on submit button, it redirects to login page.

Test passes but the details which I have entered is not added.

It works fine when I do it manually.

[Plese check this image of test runner steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDXjU.png)

Comment: please add your test script that you tried.